# I can't prove if the following series is convergent or not.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am studying complex variable by myself and I want to prove that:

$F_2(z)=\cfrac{1}{4}\pi i-\cfrac{1}{2}ln2+\left(\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right)+\cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right)^2+\cfrac{1}{3}\left(\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right)^3+\ldots$ converges if $|z-1|<\sqrt{2}$.

I have proved that  $F_1(z)=z+\cfrac{1}{2}z^2+\cfrac{1}{3}z^3+\ldots$ is a convergent series and since $F_2(z)$ is an analytic prolongation of $F_1(z)$ my intuition says that $F_2(z)$ is convergent too. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: $F_1$ is convergent under a certain condition for $z$, which you get, for example, by using the ratio test. Then all you have to do is apply said condition to the "new" $z$, call it $z'$ with $z'=\frac{z-i}{1-i}$ and "solve" for $z-1$ (because the final condition involves $|z-1|$).

Comment: The problem as written is not correct, right? Because $z=2$ satisfies $|z - 1|< \sqrt{2}$ but $\sum \frac{(2-i)^n}{n(1-i)^n}$ diverges.

Comment: Do you really mean $|z-1| < \sqrt2$?  Is it possible you mean $|z-i| < \sqrt2$?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes. The book where I got the probem says $|z-1|<\sqrt{2}$ but I think that the correct condition is $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$ since: $\left|\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right|<1$ then $|(z-i)(1+i)|<2$ and then $|(z-i)|<\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can ignore the first two terms and use the ratio test here 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{(z-i)^{n+1}}{(1-i)^{n+1}}\cdot
\frac{(1-i)^{n}}{(z-i)^n}\right| =  \left|\frac{(z-i)}{(1-i)}\right|.$$
In order for this series to converge absolutely we want 
$$\left|\frac{(z-i)}{(1-i)}\right| < 1.$$ That pretty much give what I think your looking for.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!

Comment: I think that the correct condition is $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$ since: $\left|\cfrac{z-i}{1-i}\right|<1$ then $|(z-i)(1+i)|<2$ and then $|(z-i)|<\sqrt{2}$.